# How to extend from AsyncTask as a generic base class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, abstract-class, generic-programming

There are three different implementations of an `AsyncTask`:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
public class JsonParserTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Boolean>
public class PostCommentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpRequestResult>
```

I would like them to extend a `BaseAsyncTask` which I can use for dependency injection then. The class signatur of `AsyncTask` looks like this:

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

How can I extend `AsyncTask` while maintaining the different parameters?

```
                               | DownloadTask
AsyncTask <-- BaseAsyncTask <--| JsonParserTask
                               | PostCommentTask
```

Comment: I don't get your question. You can only extend from one class. Where is `BaseAsyncTask`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
abstract class BaseAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> 
                  extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```